# need to go to login script when the person logs on

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a form in /views/wp_users/login.php that asks for the login information. But now since I am reading the login information from cookies I need to get rid of the form. But I am  not sure how to make it that the when users come to localhost/wordpress/myapp/wp_users they get redirected to index page instead of login

here is my controller

Edit:

just changed the function to login and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your `login` action and manually load the data into the Auth component

```
function login() {
   if (DO_COOKIE_CHECK) {
      //read cookie data. If user is verified load up the user data and set it with 
      // the Auth Components login method
      $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $idFromCookie);
      $this->Auth->login($this->data);
      // redirect user to index.php
   }
   //rest of code
}
```

Comment: I amnew to cake..can you explain this. $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $idFromCookie); do I have to have an id? where is it coming from? I dont have an id in cookie

Comment: You need to have a user id or a username in the cookie. Otherwise you won't know what user to load. Once you have the identifier, load up the user record and pass it to the Auth Component to log them in automatically

Comment: yes I didnt realize that $this->User->read(null, $idFromCookie); actually sends data to model. thanks